# Google Play billing 6.0 - Always return result code 4 with error

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play-console

Trying to implement purchase flow using play billing lib on sample application
Following below steps:

1. Created App on play console
2. Added item in-app-purchase
3. Created signed sample application and added in internal test and close test track
4. Added email in license testing
5. Added email in tester email list
6. Join test by clicking on web URL - Join web list
7. Not able to download apk using shareable link - Play store showing loading wheel for forever
8. Download apk from play console and installed using adb
9. Able to fetch product details
10. Purchase flow returning result code 4 with error - The item you requested is not available for purchase.

Verified license email list and product is active in same region with tester play store account